# Weird class property behaviour

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, ecmascript-next

I'm using React and bumped into something weird.

```
class C extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount = this.animate; // <---

    animate = () => ...

}
```

This did not work so I had to change the value of componentDidMount and it worked:

```
class C extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount = () => this.animate(); // Lambda is required?

    animate = () => ...

}
```

Does anyone have a good explanation as to why this is required?

Comment: Probably `animate` internally uses `this` which will be different when invoked via `this.animate()` than by a function reference to `animate`. instead try: `componentDidMount = this.animate.bind(this)` to bind the `thisArg`

Comment: I don't think that's the problem as the second code snippet worked perfectly

Comment: that indicates the invocation is the problem actually, so my suggestion should work. show the contents of `this.animate` function

Comment: What I showed is just an example. What I'm wondering about is why those two code snippets are not equivalent

Comment: Note that class properties are not part of ES6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write

```
class C extends React.Component {
   componentDidMount = this.animate; // <---
   animate = () => ...
}
```

Then `componentDidMount` is set to `undefined` because `animate` is not set at that time.

With `componentDidMount = () => this.animate();`  the `this.animate();` is resolved every time `componentDidMount` is called, that's why this does work for you.

If you write it that way:

```
class C extends React.Component {
   animate = () => ...
   componentDidMount = this.animate; // <---
}
```

Then `componentDidMount` will reference the function you assigned to `animate` before.

But if you want to define methods for a class you should check the answer of  [baao](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40819830/1960455), because then you should not use the assignment but a method definition `animate() {}`

Comment: what's with this syntax? are `animate` and `componentDidMount` supposed to be instance properties of this Component? shouldn't you write it like `animate() { /* ... */ }` or `animate: function () { /* ... */ }` etc? These look like global variables

Comment: @WilliamB the assignments are evaluated in the construction phase so yes they are instance properties. If you write `animate() { /* ... */ }` then it is a method of the class, which would be set to the prototype chain before the construction phase, so the OP for sure could also solve the problem by using `animate() { /* ... */ }` which would indeed be a better idea.

Comment: Are methods the preferred way to go? And the reason is that they are set before the construction fase? Are there any more reasons?

Comment: @justasking to be honest I cannot tell you right now how the standard defines it exactly, but If you use a transpiler like babeljs, then with the  `animate = () => ...` syntax a new instance of `() => ...` will be created for every instance of the class (so this will have a slight overhead). With `animate() {}` all instance will share the same function. You should in general always use `animate() {}`. I currently don't have a situation in mind where `animate = () => ...` might be useful.

Comment: @justasking In the comment to the other question [FelixKling](http://stackoverflow.com/users/218196)  mentioned a use case. For arrow function the `this` is bound to the `this` in which they are created (in this case the instance of the class). So if you use your functions as callbacks this might be of use, because you then you would not need to bind them manually to the instance of the class.

Answer (score 2):

You should define the animate method as a class method, not as an arrow function.

```
class C extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount = this.animate;
    animate() {}
}
```

Comment: That depends on how the method is used.

Comment: The OPs usage indicates that he thinks to use a class method, no ? @FelixKling

Comment: If it is not used anywhere else (e.g. as event handler inside `render`), then yes. That's what I meant with "depends".

Comment: @baao The question was not whether I should use methods or not. The question, formulated differently was: Why does the second code snippet work and not the first?
I think t.niese explained this very well.

Comment: @justasking your Questions title was about 'weird class property behavior', but you don't define a class property, but a function that happens to be inside a class

Comment: Yes, I agree that I should have formulated the title differently. I simply could not come up with a good title that summarized my question